# Undefined type 'Yajra\Oci8\PDO' in laravel 10.17.1 with latest Yajra composer

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

Undefined type 'Yajra\Oci8\PDO' in laravel 10.17.1 with latest Yajra composer

```
   "message": "Class \"Yajra\\Oci8\\PDO\" not found",
   "exception": "Error",
   "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bid_purchase_system_laravel\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\OtherController.php",
   "line": 38,
```

Screenshot of code

import line

```
use Yajra\Oci8\PDO;
```

[image]

oci8 also enables PHP Version 8.1.17.

[image]

[Github](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/801)

Comment: I may be mistaken, but it appears as if you're trying to use PDO directly, or rather this library directly based on a false understanding of the classes it is composed of.  The documentation for that library does not suggest the existence of that class or that line you used to import it from what I can find.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: yes, after Use PDO, I can access constant, but the procedure returns a null out value.

Comment: As far as I know PDO is built in class of PHP . 
Is this your code or this is belongs to Yajra https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKJkj.png ?

Comment: yes image code is mine

Comment: Can you add extra backslash ( \ ) at the beginning of PDO:: and try again ?
 
\PDO::PARAM_STR

Comment: Why are you using PDO directly instead of Laravel's DB facade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use below import**

```
 use POD
```

instead of

```
use Yajra\Oci8\PDO;
```